# Extract columns from 3 CSVs in to 1 CSV (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to combine 3 CSVs that contain information in the columns D and E like this with the first row called X Days:

```
    D       E      F      G
1   3 Days  4 Days      
2   $100    $200        
3   $111    $222        
4   ...     ... 
5   ...     ...
```

I want to combine the 3 CSVs in to one but leave a column blank between them like this:

```
    Data from 1st CSV:    Data from 2nd CSV:       Data from 3nd CSV:

    D       E       F     G        H        I      J       K
1   3 Days  4 Days        3 Days   4 Days          3 Days   4 Days
2   $100    $200          $300     $400            $500     $600
3   $111    $222          $333     $444            $555     $666
4    ...     ...           ...      ...             ...      ...
5    ...     ...           ...      ...             ...      ...
```

How can I combine them like this? (Without the "Data from X CSV")

Comment: Does this all have to end up in Excel?  The easiest way would be to use cut-and-paste in Excel.

Comment: The point is to automate this process in Python so that a CSV file is generated with the data combined like above.

Comment: You should be able to do this (see my answer below), but just seems weird in a lot of ways.

CSVs are best at storing data and secondary at displaying it. It seems like you want these blank columns because that will ease the display. If this is a project of any more than trivial size it may be better to separate out that storing from displaying.

It also seems very strange to have your first row be what seem like your column headers (3 days, 4 days). Since you have 3 sources that use those same headers, having the header be `F1_3_days`, `F1_4_days`, `F2_3_days`, etc seems better

Comment: Data will be added on top of those headers, its basically to compare multiple cities and the cost of staying in them for X days depending on the season.

Answer (score 0):

So, you just open all of your CSV files in parallel.  As long as they keep feeding input, you create new rows on output.  This code stops as soon as the FIRST CSV file ends.  If you need to run until the longest file, that will take more work.  You'd use this like:

```
python merge.py aaa.csv bbb.csv ccc.csv
```

You could use glob to allow wildcards.

```
import sys
import csv

fls = [csv.reader(open(f)) for f in sys.argv[1:]]
fout = csv.writer(open('out.csv','w'))

try:
    while True:
        newrow = []
        for i,f in enumerate(fls):
            row = next(f)
            if i == 0:
                newrow.extend( row[0:5] + [''] )
            else:
                newrow.extend( row[3:5] + [''] )
        fout.writerow( newrow )
        print(newrow)
except StopIteration:
    print('Done')
```

Comment: That was a quick response thanks but unfortunately it adds a blank row between every row

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, but anyone who works with Python CSV files needs to know to try adding `newline=''` to the `csv.writer` call when that happens.

Comment: Yeah you are right I don't know how did I forgot about that. You are a genius this works, but I have one last question. How do I keep the columns A,B,C from the first CSV file while adding D & E's from the other files? In my example I started from D but there's actually data in the A,B,C columns that I would like to keep in the new generated csv file.

Comment: Tricker.  You COULD do `for i,f in enumerate(fls):` and `if i == 0:` / `newrow.extend( row[0:3] )`.

Answer (score 0):

read all three csvs in to dataframes and then use `pd.concat(...,axis=1)` to concat them as new columns.

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
df3 = pd.read_csv(file3)

df1['F'] = '' #making those blank columns
df2['I'] = ''
df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
df_final.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Just like in the answer from _Tim Roberts_ This works!  but how do I keep the columns A,B,C from the first CSV file while adding D & E's from the other files?

Comment: if you just want to add D & E from the other files, you can drop all the other columns from the other CSVs, and rename things as well. `df.drop(columns={...}` and `df.rename(columns={...})`.